# Somar resultados de vários select count no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, query, variáveis

Eu estou querendo somar todos os clientes que eu tenho em todas as minhas bases, então para isso estou fazendo a seguinte *query*:

```
SET @total = 0;

USE BASE x1; SELECT @total:= @total +COUNT(1) FROM clientes;

USE BASE x2; SELECT @total:= @total +COUNT(1) FROM clientes;
```

no cenário atual a minha variável está pegando o valor dela mesmo e somando com o valor de `COUNT(1)`;

Mas a cada *query* executada, é exibido um resultado, 
Eu gostaria que fosse exibido apenas o resultado final!

Comment: Um simples `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clientes` já não vai te retornar seu total de clientes? Ou você quer fazer isso com variáveis mesmo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode somar o resultado de um SubSelect

```
SELECT 
     SUM(CLIENTES) 
FROM (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS CLIENTES FROM X1.CLIENTES
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS CLIENTES FROM X2.CLIENTES
     )  AS T
```

Comment: Erro SQL (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias, depois de fechar o parenteses do FROM tive que colocar um 'as total'... ai deu certo, editei a sua resposta!